# How to delegate authorisation to external Auth 2.0 services

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asana, asana-api

I'm working on a service that provides smart (hopefully) integration of different services supporting `OAuth 2.0`. The focus of our tool is on team work flow improvement, so we're combining `Slack`, `GitHub`, `Asana` (issue tracker), `Cezanne` (hr tool), etc.

We have ui and backend that work with all those tools (user is authorised to all of them, so I have required access and refresh tokens). We need to be able to hide different parts of the ui depending on person's role in a specific tool. Let's take `GitHub` as an example. The user can be a repository owner, contributor, company owner (for business account), etc, so those user might need different ui based on their rights.

Originally I was hesitant implementing authorisation on my own (another custom authorisation system is the last thing this world needs), I wanted to take advantage of other services' authorisation mechanisms and just create a lightweight wrapper around them. It seemed like a reasonable idea at first, but I can't figure out how to implement it and Google doesn't give valuable advice which means: 99.99% I'm trying to do something stupid, 00.01% I'm trying to do something rare/innovative.

I hoped to take advantage of `OAuth 2.0` but it doesn't seem to support what we need. The closest thing is scopes but it doesn't look very relevant to our scenario.

The only idea I have for now is to create our own authorisation system and integrate other services using kind of reverse engineering. So I would request user's GitHub account details using API and apply him roles in our system appropriately: Owner for repository A, contributor for repository B, owner of company C, etc. I will have to reverse-engineer the permission for each role (i. e. repository owner can not change company name). And we would have to keep user roles for each service: so instead of typical Admin/User/Manager/etc. we will get: OwnerOfGitHubRepository (for repositoryA), ManagerOfAsanaTeam (for team B), etc.

It would be awesome if `OAuth 2.0` services had an endpoint that would return the permissions available for a current user.

I'm not a security engineer, so I might be missing something obvious. So wanted to ask you guys for advice before investing into the implementation mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

The word, "authorization", is used in two different contexts.

In one context, authorization means ***"who has what permissions"***. Solutions for this authorization is ***"identity management"***.

In the other context, authorization means ***"who grants what permissions to whom"***. Solutions for this authorization is ***"OAuth"***.

In some cases, you may have to handle these two authorizations simultaneously. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377012/1174054) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378565/1174054) for details.

Comment: Thanks for proving OAuth 2.0 is not the solution for the outlined problem. Would love to hear your thoughts on the solution outlined in the question (I changed it a little bit to be more clear).

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with identityserver4. 
[This Issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2632) for identityserver3 from last year may interest you.
But I'm afraid most providers don't support this oauth2 profile (yet). 
[UMA](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/rec-uma-core.html%20UMA) seems to be an oauth2 way to enable fine grained authorization, but may not be the best solution.